# How to search across all the resources relative to a web page with Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

A web page may cause the browser to download many css styles, ajax requests, html document, javascript. I'd like to search which part of the source code is requesting a specific URL. But it seems not to work as I supposed. I did something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It could be achieved by pressing `CTRL - SHIFT - F` it searches everywhere in the files.

[image]